# Is it possible to run a DHCP server?

Tags: debian, archlinux, networking

Our home router is terrible at remembering configured static IPs, I'd like to use my RasPi instead. Is there anything particular I need to consider when setting it up?

Comment: Please can you include the distro you are using. The answer will vary per distro

Comment: @Jivings None yet, what would be a good one to use?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16754/how-to-share-the-internet-connection

Comment: I shall give my answer for Arch Linux and Debian then.

Comment: Interesting idea, are you planning to implement internal throttling?

Comment: Only a DHCP server or a gateway as well?

Comment: @Tibor Only for DHCP. We have a router which is our gateway, but it's DHCP service is effectively broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your Raspberry Pi, all you would need to do is install the `dhcp` package.

Arch:

```
sudo pacman -S dhcp
```

Debian:

```
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

You then edit the configuration file at `/etc/conf.d/dhcp` which tells the dhcp server which interface on which to listen with this line:

```
DHCP4_ARGS="... eth0"
```

You then start the server daemon with:

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/dhcp4 start
```

Now any clients that broadcast for an IP connected to `eth0` will be managed by the dhcp server.

Comment: Why do I need two network interfaces? I'm not routing traffic through the Pi (we have an all-in-one wireless router/modem, so that's not possible anyway), just using it to assign addresses.

Comment: @TomMedley Ignore that part then. The rest still applies.

Comment: Is [this meta answer](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/101/141) incorrect when it says that `sudo` isn't installed on Arch by default? If so, might this answer be a little confusing to newcomers?

Comment: @MarkBooth I forgot about that. I think we have to make some assumptions occasionally. Such as that any user who wants to set up a dhcp server already knows what sudo is. If not, they can ask in a comment.